# Xamarin Android Save sms

Tags: c#, android, datetime

I have the following code

```
var context = Application.Context.ApplicationContext;
var values = new ContentValues();
values.Put("address", "+27824318637");
values.Put("body", "Testing C");
values.Put("read", false);
values.Put("date", "???");
context.ContentResolver.Insert(Uri.Parse("content://sms/inbox"), values);
```

However I do not know how to format the current datetime,
I Tried ToString()
I Tried (Now - MinValue).TotalMiliSeconds
And also Now.ToString("ddMMyyhhmmss")

None gives the correct date in the inbox always 1970 january 2 or 1

Comment: I don't understand. Where is your `DateTime` value exactly and what is it's value? What do you want as a result after you format it?

Comment: DateTime is DateTime.Now
But I managed to succeed

Comment: So, how do you format it exactly? What do you want as a result when you format it?

Comment: I only had to convert it to a Java.Util.Date and then get the Integer value from there (which worked as it should)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to succeed by Converting the DateTime to a Java.Util.Date
Here is my code

```
    private void SaveToInbox(ShortMessages shortMessage)
    {
        var now = shortMessage.MessageDate.HasValue ? shortMessage.MessageDate.Value : DateTime.Now;
        var d = new Date((now.Year - 1900), now.Month - 1, now.Day, now.Hour, now.Minute, now.Second);
        var context = Application.Context.ApplicationContext;
        var values = new ContentValues();
        values.Put("address", shortMessage.From);
        values.Put("body", shortMessage.Message);
        values.Put("read", false);
        values.Put("date", d.Time);
        context.ContentResolver.Insert(Android.Net.Uri.Parse("content://sms/inbox"), values);
    }
```